# cakephp multilingual dynamic content from database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, dynamic, multilingual

I want to develop website with option to select language
at the time I do not know about how to structure my database tables i.e 
either I should add separate fields for each language e.g
`tbl_posts
id, title_en,title_fr,description_en,description_fr,....`

or should I get help of google translate at run time
or there is something else easy to do this

secondly I will need to have `URLs` like
`www.domain.com/en/posts/` & `www.domain.com/fr/posts/`

third what other things should I keep in mind to develop multilingual website.
looking for standardized, more optimized, easy manageable and fully dynamic solution.

Comment: I googled many articles bu most of them are for static content while some are specific for limited task like routing only, still confused how to merge and decide and make overall plan

Comment: You can't have searched particularly hard as there is a whole section on translations and internationalizing a CakePHP app on the official documentation website! I'd share the relevant link but you've not stated which version of Cake you're using.

Comment: currently I am using 2.6

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html

Answer (score 2):

Cakephp
Step 1: In your lib/Cake/basic.php add function

```
if (!function_exists('__dbt')) {
    function __dbt($text, $args = null) {
            if($text==null){
                return null;
            }else{
                $languageUse =  Configure::read('Config.language');
                if($languageUse!='en-us' && $languageUse!='eng'){
                    $modelName =  ucfirst($languageUse)."Translation";
                    $model = ClassRegistry::init($modelName);
                    $data = $model->find('first',array('fields'=>array('translation'),'conditions'=>array("text"=>"$text")));
                    if(!empty($data[$modelName]) && $data[$modelName]['translation']!=''){
                        return $data[$modelName]['translation'];//die('1');
                    }else{
                    // Please copy & paste below code from your basic.php __() function   
                    App::uses('I18n', 'I18n');
                    $translated = I18n::translate($text);
                    $arguments = func_get_args();
                    return I18n::insertArgs($translated, array_slice($arguments, 1));
                    }
                }else{
                    // Please copy & paste below code from your basic.php __() function   
                    App::uses('I18n', 'I18n');
                    $translated = I18n::translate($text);
                    $arguments = func_get_args();
                    return I18n::insertArgs($translated, array_slice($arguments, 1));
                }
            }
}
```

}

Step 2: create table on basis of language you want to use
Note: table name should be prefix locale + _tranlations
example: hin_translations, tha_translations etc.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hin_translations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `translation` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

In above table add english string in your text column and its translation in translation column.

Step 3: where ever you want to change language string either from database or locale po file just use

```
__dbt("Write your string here");
```

:) enjoy your multilingual site

Comment: Special Note: In your database table add english string in text column and its translation in description coloumn